# Facebook registration plugin is not displaying fields

Tags: plugins, facebook-graph-api, iframe, field

I have the following facebook registration plugin that lets user register through their FB account. Following is the`iFrame` that does this job.

```
       <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
         client_id=239703062769103&
         redirect_uri=http://www.booze-log.com/kruskirety/profileThis.php
         fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
          scrolling="auto"
          frameborder="no"
          style="border:none"
          allowTransparency="true"
          width="100%"
          height="330">
     </iframe>
```

When this displays, only the name field of the user is visible and the rest-birthday, gender, location, email are not visible. I tried setting the fields to JSON type as well but the problem still persists.

Here is the [screenshot](http://www.diigo.com/item/image/24bm9/akw9?size=o) of what the problem looks like

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I have found the answer but I wouldn't be able to submit it for another 7 hours due to reputation constraints.

Comment: Thanks jbloom that'd be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the answer. It was a minor missing of `&`-ampersand,  after `profileThis.php` in `redirect_uri` that was causing this issue. A silly mistake costs both time and effort I reckon.